# Populate <select> <option> using v-for loop in VueJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuejs2, frontend

I am new to VueJS and I just figure out how to populate Select Options box using v-for loop.

```
<select>
    <option v-for="person in persons" :value="personid">{{ personname }}</option>
</select>
```

Here is the list I have.

```
"persons": {
        "2": "Person1",
        "3": "Person2",
        "4": "Person3"
    }
```

This is our desired output.

```
<select id="persons">
    <option value="3">Person1</option>
    <option value="4">Person2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: here your answer: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.htmll#Select

Comment: It's well documented: [v-for with an Object](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-with-an-Object).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luckily for you, Vue can loop through the properties in an Object as described in [v-for with an Object](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-with-an-Object).

I've also included a snippet below which should help you achieve what you want.

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.config.devtools = false;

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: () => {
    return {
      persons: {
        "2": "Person1",
        "3": "Person2",
        "4": "Person3"
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <select id="persons">
    <option v-for="(name, id) in persons" :value="id">{{name}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are almost done, just improve that select:

```
<select id="persons" >
  <option
    v-for="(value, key) in persons"
    :value="key"
    :key="key"
  >{{ value }}</option>
</select>
```